# Changing the Network adapter name Programmatically in windows with Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, powershell, network-programming

I know that it is possible to change the network adapter in windows using the netsh command in console. but I need to do this in Qt using C++. I have tried to use QProcess to call netsh but command prompt needs admin right. also there is space in my adapter name that make it also not easy to run. Is there any library in Qt capable of changing Network adapter name without using QProcess and calling windows commands in it?

**Update 1:**
When I run the program with admin right and set the \" for having " inside of my string I can change the adapter name, using QProcess and netsh command.

```
QProcess p;
QString pi_network = "original adapter name";
p.start("netsh interface set interface name = \""+pi_network+"\" newname = \"MyAdapter\"");
```

[image]

Comment: With PowerShell you need to run as Administrator. `Get-NetAdapter -Name 'LAN-Verbindung 21' | Rename-NetAdapter -NewName Renamed -WhatIf`

Comment: Does your application have admin rights - so the problem is just invoking netsh with the correct rights? This command couldn't be called from an application with user rights only.

Comment: yes, with the admin right I solved the problem. to me using the QProcess for such a functionality is like a workaround but anyhow it does the job. I used netsh as I mentioned above. Thank you guys.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to answer your own question on SO, so you'd might as well submit your findings as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post it as an answer, because it might help someone (as MrEricSir said in the comments).

you can use netsh command, but be aware that you should run your program with administrator right in windows.

```
QProcess p;
QString pi_network = "original adapter name";
p.start("netsh interface set interface name = \""+pi_network+"\" newname = \"new network adapter name\"");
p.waitForFinished();
p.close();
```