# Wireguard - How to change the adapter friendly-name on windows in Golang?

Tags: windows, go, wireguard

I downloaded the wireguard-windows repository and I navigated to this path
`wireguard-windows/tunnel/winipcfg/types.go`

in this [types.go](https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-windows/blob/master/tunnel/winipcfg/types.go#L633) file I found this function:

```
// FriendlyName method returns a user-friendly name for the adapter. For example: "Local Area Connection 1."
// This name appears in contexts such as the ipconfig command line program and the Connection folder.
func (addr *IPAdapterAddresses) FriendlyName() string {
    if addr.friendlyName == nil {
        return ""
    }
    return windows.UTF16PtrToString(addr.friendlyName)
}
```

When creating a connection in this Wireguard desktop app it's creating a network adapter with the name "Wireguard Tunnel", is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not something related to Go. It's more about Windows: [ns-iptypes-ip_adapter_addresses_lh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iptypes/ns-iptypes-ip_adapter_addresses_lh)
You can change friendly name in Windows registry as far as I know.

Comment: But this application (build in Go and C#) it setting the name to Wireguard Tunnel, so it's coming from somewhere from that app, I'm trying to find where.

Comment: As it mentioned in the comment for [IPAdapterAddresses](https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-windows/blob/master/tunnel/winipcfg/types_64.go#L32) function : `This is a modified and extended version of windows.IpAdapterAddresses.`

Comment: when you said that I can change the friendly name in the Windows registry, did you mean manually and run it? or you know a way to change it in the app so it would show another name as I run the app.

Comment: Not sure, but may be this will help: [Changing the Network adapter name Programmatically in windows with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49968571/6731606)